# Binding a ListView to a property in the same Class

Tags: wpf

I have a Listview and i want to bind it to a list declared on the same class(codebehind)

```
public ObservableCollection<Slot> ListViewList { get; set; }

<ListView x:Name="ListViewSlots" Margin="0,230,0,0" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserControl.ListViewList}" >
```

But is not working, i tried setting the datacontext of the usercontrol to self and desnt works.

Comment: i Think was my fault, i was setting the list after this.InitializeComponent(); i move it before that line and now is working :s

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the `DataContext` of the UserControl to *the list*, and then setting the `ItemsSource` of the ListView to that?

ie.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
```

Comment: Yes but still doesn't works. but anyway i dont want the entire usercontrol be binded to the list, i only want the listview binded to it.

Comment: My approach in that case would be to make a separate object which contains the list and can be bound as the DataContext of the UserControl. **But if you simply must use the code-behind to contain the list...** Can you not reference the ListView itself in the code-behind and set *its* DataContext? I.e.: `this.ListViewSlots.ItemsSource = ListViewList;`

Comment: Yes that way is currently working, on codebehind, but i want to set that on xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Window

```
<Window ...
   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
>
```

and then your ListView becomes

```
<Listview ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewList}">...
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to introduce your list to the resources of the class:

```
public List<string> ListViewList
{
    get{ return (List<string> Resources["ListViewList"];}
    set{ Resources["ListViewList"] = value;}
}
```

or use ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _listViewList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> ListViewList { get { return _listViewList; } }
```

then in XAML, you can bind something to it:

```
<ListView>
    <ItemsPanel
        ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewList}"
    />
</ListView>
```

and as Joel said you need to set the DataContext of the entire window
(or just the block you're dealing with) to self:

```
<Window ...
   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
>
```